# How to escape a single quote on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I need to export a password that is like this:

```
export PASSWORD='vfR"&aDA'GzV3(Yg'
```

But the above does not work when I do the below three combinations with backslash.

```
export PASSWORD='vfR"&aDA\'GzV3(Yg'
export PASSWORD='vfR\"&aDA\'GzV3(Yg'
export PASSWORD='vfR\"&aDA\'GzV3\(Yg'
```

Comment: Are the single `'` at the start and end part of PASSWORD?

Comment: @jww Please stop flagging shell questions as off topic. Despite the overlap with other Stack Exchange sites shell scripting is on topic here.

Comment: The shell *is* a programming language; the fact that it is extensively used from a REPL and is optimized for running other programs doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `export PASSWORD="vfR\"&aDA'GzV3(Yg"`. I think the single quotes are preventing the escaping slash from doing what you expect. So, try double quotes. You can view the answer to a question on single versus double quotes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Answer (score 1):

In single-quotes, escapes don't work; they're just a backslash character. The *only* thing that has a special meaning after a single-quote is another single-quote, and that always marks the end of the single-quoted section. As a result, you cannot embed a single-quote in a single-quoted string.

You have several options. You can end the single-quoted *section* of the string and use something else to protect the single-quote:

```
# Single-quoted string, escaped single-quote, then another single-quoted string:
export PASSWORD='vfR"&aDA'\''GzV3(Yg'
# Single-quoted string, double-quoted single-quote, then another single-quoted string:
export PASSWORD='vfR"&aDA'"'"'GzV3(Yg'
```

Or use a double-quoted string instead (and then escape any double-quotes, backslashes, dollar signs, backquotes, etc that you want in the string):

```
export PASSWORD="vfR\"&aDA'GzV3(Yg"
```

Or you could skip quotes entirely and just escape everything individually:

```
export PASSWORD=vfR\"\&aDA\'GzV3\(Yg
```

Comment: Let me try out and get back